# Advance search filter using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to create the advanced search query , that allow the users to enter as many filters as they want. this filter contain different Asp controls like dropdownlist and checkbox.
This is the query that i use , the problem is that it require the enter all filter to work ,i need it to accept any collection of filters .

this query work only one single button.
 (please please post your answers with modifying my code for better understanding.

I will paramitrized query later.

```
 public partial class Searchpage : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    string price1;
    string price2;
    string osx;
    string checktwog;
    string checkthreeg;
    string checkfourg;
    string phonetype;
    string cam;
    string ram;
    string q;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
    con.Open();
    try
    {
        price1 = Convert.ToString(Session["price1"]);
        price2 = Convert.ToString(Session["price2"]);
        osx = Convert.ToString(Session["osx"]);
        checktwog = Convert.ToString(Session["checktwog"]);
        checkthreeg = Convert.ToString(Session["checkthreeg"]);
        checkfourg = Convert.ToString(Session["checkfourg"]);
        phonetype = Convert.ToString(Session["phonetype"]);
        cam = Convert.ToString(Session["cam"]);
        ram = Convert.ToString(Session["ram"]);
        q = "select * from legacy where price >= " + price1 + " and price <= " + price2 + " and os = '" + osx + "' and gprsedge = '" + checktwog + "' and threeg= '" + checkthreeg + "' and fourg='" + checkfourg + "' and touchscreen='" + phonetype + "' and camera='" + cam + "' and ram='" + ram +"'";
        SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = q;
        SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
```

Comment: This is not safe at all. If I were you I would move all the sql into a stored procedure and pass in those parameters after they have been sanitized. Also you should check if the parameters are null or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following algorithm

```
var filters = new List<filterItem>();
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "price", op: ">=", value: Session["price1"]));
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "price", op: "<=", value: Session["price2"]));
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "os", op: "=", value: Session["osx"]));
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "gprsedge", op: "=", value: Session["checktwog"]));
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "threeg", op: "=", value: Session["checkthreeg"]));
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "fourg", op: "=", value: Session["checkfourg"]));
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "touchscreen", op: "=", value: Session["phonetype"]));
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "camera", op: ">=", value: Session["cam"]));
filters.Add(new filterItem(field: "ram", op: ">=", value: Session["ram"]));

var conditions = filters
    .Where(f => f.Value != null)
    .Select((filter, index) => {
        var parameterName = string.Format("p{0}", index);// eg: p0, p1, ...
        var parameterValue = Convert.ToString(filter.Value);
        //Add parameter to SelectParameters
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(parameterName, parameterValue);
        //Construct filter for query, eg price >= @p0
        var condition = string.Format("{0} {1} @{2}", filter.Field, filter.Operator, parameterName);
        return condition;
    });

var predicate = string.Empty;
if (conditions.Count() > 0) {
    predicate = string.Format("WHERE {0}", string.Join(" AND ", conditions));
}

var query = "SELECT * FROM legacy";

var selectCommand = string.Join(" ", query, predicate).Trim();

SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = selectCommand;
```

Where the type `filterItem` is defined as

```
class filterItem {
    public filterItem(string field, string op, object value) {
        this.Field = field;
        this.Operator = op;
        this.Value = value;
    }
    public string Field { get; private set; }
    public string Operator { get; private set; }
    public object Value { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: and please tell me about the var conditions = filters
    .Where(f => f.Value != null)
    .Select((filter, index) => {
        var parameterName = string.Format("p{0}", index);// eg: p0, p1, ...
        var parameterValue = Convert.ToString(filter.Value);
        //Add parameter to SelectParameters
        SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add(parameterName, parameterValue);
        //Construct filter for query, eg price >= @p0
        var condition = string.Format("{0} {1} @{2}", filter.Field, filter.Operator, parameterName);
        return condition;
    });

Comment: how to paramitrized where you wrote comments plse compleete this post for me to better understanding

Comment: like         //Add parameter to SelectParameters and //Construct filter for query, eg price >= @p0

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like (code not tested)

```
List<string> conditions = new List<string>();
if (price1 != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param1", price);
    conditions.Add(" price >= @param1 ");
}

if (price2 != null)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@param2");
    conditions.Add(" price <= @param2 ");
}

.....

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("select * from legacy ");
if(conditions.Count > 0)
{
    sb.Append("WHERE ");
    sb.Append(string.Join(" AND ", conditions));
}
```